# How would i change a <div> border colour when a drop down box is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am trying to get a HTML `<div>` to change its border colour when I select one of the drop down boxes in side it.

I have tried something simple like:

```
<style>
#select_Academic:hover{border:1px solid red;}
#select_Academic:focus{border:1px solid red;}
#select_Academic:active{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
```

The html is:

```
  echo "<div id=\"Options\">";

 include "select.class.php"; 
echo "<form id=\"select_Academic\">";
echo "<div class=\"Select_Option\">"; 
echo "Choose a subject:";
echo "</div>";
echo "<select style=\"width:200px; margin-left:10px;\" id=\"category\" name=\"cat\" >";
echo $opt->ShowCategory();
echo "</select>";
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";

echo "<div class=\"Select_Option\">";
echo "Choose a section:";
echo "</div>";              
echo "<select style=\"width:200px; margin-left:10px;\"id=\"type\">";
echo "<option value=\"%\">";
echo "Section";
echo "</option>";
echo "</select>";
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";

echo "<div class=\"Select_Option\">";
echo "Choose a principle:";
echo "</div>";
echo "<select style=\"width:200px; margin-left:10px;\"id=\"principle\">";
echo "<option value=\"%\">";
echo "Principle";
echo "</option>";
echo "</select>";
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";
echo "<input style=\"margin-left:10px;\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Search\"/>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</div>";
```

but when the mouse has left the div the border colour is no longer showing and I understand why just wondering whats the best possible way to do this.

I have JavaScript linked to these boxes I don't know if you could add something into this JavaScript to achieve the same results.

The JavaScript I have got :

```
 $(document).ready(function()
        {

                $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("select#category").change(function()
                {
                    var id = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
                    $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
                    $("select#type").html("<option>wait...</option>");
                    $.post("select_type.php", {id:id}, function(data)
                    {
                        $("select#type").removeAttr("disabled");
                        $("select#type").html(data);
                    });
                });

            $("select#principle").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#type").change(function(){
                var id = $("select#type option:selected").attr('value');
                $("select#principle").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("select#principle").html("<option>wait...</option>");
                $.post("select_principle.php", {id:id}, function(data){
                    $("select#principle").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("select#principle").html(data);
                });
            });

            $("select#career").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#jobrole").change(function(){
                var id = $("select#jobrole option:selected").attr('value');
                $("select#career").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("select#career").html("<option>wait...</option>");
                $.post("select_career.php", {id:id}, function(data){
                    $("select#career").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("select#career").html(data);
                });
            });

            $("form#select_Academic").submit(function()
            {
                var cat = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
                var type = $("select#type option:selected").attr('value');
                var princ = $("select#principle option:selected").attr('value');
                $txt = cat + "#" + type + "#" + princ;
                var id = $("select#type option:selected").attr('value');
                $.post("get_results.php", {comboboxselections:$txt}, function(data){
                    $("#ResultList").html(''+data);
                });
                if(cat>0 && type>0 && princ>0)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#ResultList").html("you must choose three options!");
                }
                return false;
            });

            $("form#Select_Job").submit(function()
            {
                var job = $("select#jobrole option:selected").attr('value');
                var car = $("select#career option:selected").attr('value');
                $txt1 = job + "#" + car;
                var id = $("select#career option:selected").attr('value');
                $.post("get_jobresults.php", {comboboxselections1:$txt1}, function(data){
                    $("#ResultList").html(''+data);
                    });         
                if(job>0 && car>0)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#ResultList").html("you must choose two options!");
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
        </script>
```

any help would be much appreciated I am open to all suggestions such as jquery

Comment: can you share the html also

Comment: Including the jQuery scripts.

Comment: Added in the html @ArunPJohny and I currently don't know if there is a jquery way of doing this that is what i am asking if anybody knows of a way

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: A jQuery way is quite easy. How and when exactly would you like to remove the border again? When clicking outside the "activated" div?

Comment: @j08691 that is the exact HTML that I am using ignore the php this is just echoing it to the screen

Comment: It's easier for us to debug without having to parse your PHP. But hey, if you wanna leave it go ahead, but I'm done looking at the question at that point.

Comment: `$('#select_Academic').find('select').change(function(){
        $('#select_Academic').css('border','solid red 1px');
    });` Should do the trick

Comment: @j08691 ok that is fine

Comment: close the php tag when you write so much html and reopen it after, it's unreadable like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html:

```
<div id="dv">
    <select id="ddl">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option>One</option>
        <option>Two</option>
    </select>   
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
 $( "#ddl" ).change(function() {
                alert($(this).val());
    $('#dv').addClass('active');                 
                });
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/K7YmM/

Comment: OK this has worked perfectly I just had to implement this into the java script that I already had thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the drop down's `change` event and in the event handler, apply your CSS class based on the selected value. Here is a JSFiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/6AUg2/2/

Comment: I tried this option and could not get this to work I don't know if it is the same as the other answer where I cannot refer to the classes name @mbcrute